# captura de pantalla conwysiwyg

Tags: email, wysiwyg

quiero implementar  un wysiwyg o un input que mande una capruta de pantalla desde un formulario y enviarlopor correo mediante php pero me manda un error al intentar enviar, no se coomo implementarlo no se si haya otro metodo o como podria implementarlo, o talvez haya manera de hacer un input que acepte captura de pantallas.

este es el codigo del wysisyg tomo el valor como si fuera cualquier input php pero al mandar la imagen por correo genera un codigo enorme, esto por que tengo entendido que el wysiwyg es una especie de traductor html

```
    <form action="enviar.php" method="post" name="orden" id ="orden"  style="margin-bottom: 3cm; margin-top: 1cm; background-color: #E7EEF2;">
    
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Example textarea</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="text"  name="text" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    
    <div class="d-grid gap-2 mt-5 mx-5">
    <button type="submit" class="btn " style="background-color: #A22929; color: #ffffff;">ENVIAR</button>
    <input type="button" onclick="jsSave()" value="guardar">
    </div>
    </form>


<script src="//js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
```

Comment: Hola, deberías pasarte por las secciones [aks] y [tour]; luego podrás [edit] tu pregunta y pegar el código en lugar de una imagen.

Comment: listo ya modifique el codigo, 
estas son las librerias para convertir el textarea 
<script src="//js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
   
no se si alla manera de tomar ese valor como imagen o como podria para subir una captura de pantalla mediante un formulario a un correo

Comment: que se supone que es wysiwyg ???

Comment: es un editor de texto para crear contenido html y tienen otras funciones lo que necesito es algo asi como la caja de comentarios de esta pagina en donde el contenido lo pueda mandar por correo osubir a una base de datos, no logro hacerlo con las imagenes.
el proyecto trata de un helpdesk